How does the spectral radius of the Hessian of a box-constrained polynomial with random coefficients change with degree and dimension?
It seems that spectral radius of a symmetric random matrix with i.i.d. entries 0 mean and some assumptions on variance converges to $\sqrt(n)$ where $n$ is the number of dimensions:
e.g.
https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.13631 and
https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.13631
From some numerical experiments I have done ( up to $n=1000$ ) it seems that for entries drawn the Uniform Distribution (-1,1) (i.e. the above restrictions on variance do not hold)  there might be convergence to some constant*$\sqrt(n)$.
The above, of course, exactly corresponds to the case when the Hessian is of a polynomial of degree 2 with $[-1,1]^n$ domain and random coefficients drawn from U(-1,1) (which is what I'm interested in).
But what happens when we increase the degree?
Then the Hessian is obviously not constant and for a given x in the domain, when we randomly choose the coefficients, the entries of the Hessian are no longer i.i.d. and similarly for a given set of coefficients.
Is there anything we can say about the spectral radius in this case?
Apologies if I'm missing something obvious.
